# Why does [IO.File]::WriteAllText concatenate the Get-Content -tail ## output, and Set-Content does not?

Tags: powershell

If this is a duplicate question for this specific issue, forgive me and please kindly point me in the right direction - I have not seen this in Stack Overflow so far.

I'm using `PowerShell` to run a set of commands as follows to find 'NUL' char's in a file.  (`-replace` works just fine - this is not my problem)

```
$findString = '\x00'
$replString = 'DERPS'
$foo = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\SomeFile.txt")
$bar = $foo -replace $findString, $replString
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\SomeFile_2.txt", $bar)
$Lines = Get-Content "C:\SomeFile_2.txt" -tail 10
#I have also used the following with the same effect:
#$Lines = Get-Content "C:\SomeFile_2.txt" |Select-Object -last 10
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\FOOBARRED.txt", $Lines)
Set-Content "C:\NOT_FOOBARRED.txt" $Lines
```

What I'm experiencing is with `[IO.File]` it concatenates the last 10 lines into one string:

```
Line 1 of 10 Line 2 of 10 Line 3 of 10 Line 4 of 10 Line 5 of 10 Line 6 of 10 Line 7 of 10 Line 8 of 10 Line 9 of 10 DERPSDERPSDERPSDERPSDERPS
```

With `Set-Content` my output looks correct:

```
Line 1 of 10
Line 2 of 10
Line 3 of 10
Line 4 of 10
Line 5 of 10 
Line 6 of 10 
Line 7 of 10
Line 8 of 10
Line 9 of 10
DERPSDERPSDERPSDERPSDERPS
```

Can anyone explain what the difference is?  Is it correct to assume the "WriteAllText" Command works when it's a raw format, but if it's processed in anyway it will accept the data as one large blob?

Comment: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` is a .NET library method being accessed directly in PowerShell, so it is rather "raw" compared to PowerShell's `Set-Content` which itself is a huge abstraction.

Comment: That said, I don't know why your linebreaks are being lost...

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this.

Comment: With `Get-Content` you read an array of lines. `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` is for writing a (multiline) string and if you feed it an array, the elements are concatenated with a space character rather than a newline. Try `[IO.File]::WriteAllLines()` which is the .Net method for writing arrays.

Comment: But he is using `[IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\SomeFile.txt")` which is a multi-line string and `[IO.File]::WriteAllText(...)` to save it, `SomeFile_2.txt` from his first example should look just fine.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon No, his code uses `$Lines = Get-Content` for the part where the result is the space-joined string

Comment: @Theo I see what you mean, I might be missing something or my English is really bad but there is no reference to which one is the concatenated file unless "barred" means concatenated ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Your English is better than mine most of the time ;) and I'll have to google for 'barred'. Sounds like 'locked up' (behind bars) or something.. Anyway, I'm on mobile now, so I'm glad mklement0 explained in detail with his answer

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, when something is "FooBarred" it's usually interpreted as "Messed **U**p **B**eyond **A**ll **R**epair." Typically however, a word starting with "F" meaning something similar to "Messed" which I won't type out here is used instead. . .  The original Acronym as I understood is "FUBAR" (spelled out above, minus "F" word). . . so - "FOOBARRED" is the file that's all messed up - the "NOT_FOOBARRED" is the one which came out just right.  Also - "foo" and "bar" are often used as variable substitutes when providing code samples - I see it most often in Batch code samples oddly.

Comment: Also - @SantiagoSquarzon, You are absolutely correct with `SomeFile_2.txt` - this content comes out just fine!  This was what led me to my confusion to start with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`[IO.File]::WriteAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.WriteAllText) expects a *single* (potentially multiline) string** as the argument to its `contents` parameter.

By contrast, **`Get-Content -Tail 10` returns an *array* of strings** (when captured in a variable), each containing a *line* from the file with the trailing newline stripped.

PowerShell performs many automatic type conversions, and while they're usually helpful, sometimes they're not: here, it **automatically converts the array to a single-line string by concatenating the elements with a single space each**<sup>[1]</sup>, as the following example demonstrates:

```sh
PS> "$('line1', 'line2')" # stringify an array
line1 line2  # elements were joined with a space
```

This automatic stringification of the array stored in `$Lines` in the context of your `[IO.File]::WriteAllText()` call caused your problem.

Therefore, **use [`[IO.File]::WriteAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.WriteAllLines) instead** (note: *Lines* rather than *Text*), which **expects an *array* of strings** and writes its elements as lines to the file, terminated with a (platform-native) newline each.

In other words: It acts like `Set-Content` when given an *array* of strings, though note that in *Windows PowerShell* you'll end up with an *ANSI*-encoded file by default with `Set-Content`, whereas .NET - and now *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, consistently - default to BOM-less UTF-8.

---

As an aside:

- A PowerShell alternative to `[IO.File]::ReadAllText()` is to use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) with the `-Raw` switch.
- You're already aware of [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) as the PowerShell alternative to `[IO.File]::WriteAllLines()`. It can also act as an alternative to `[IO.File]::WriteAllText()` if you pass it a *single, multiline* string and also specify the
  `-NoNewline` switch.

---

<sup>[1] A space character is the *default*, which you can override via the [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs), though that is rarely seen in practice.</sup>

Comment: ‍♂️ - YEP!  WriteAllLines - I _saw this parameter_ but thought it might have been for numerical purposes or something only.  I much prefer the `[IO.File]` Methods as I can specify the Encoding I need in a way I understand better, (and by default - most things I work w/ are UTF8) - This is exactly what I needed 

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @k1dfr0std. The following won't help you if you're stuck with Windows PowerShell, but note that in PowerShell (Core) 7+ BOM-less UTF-8 is now the _consistent_ default, across cmdlets, and the `-Encoding` parameters now accept `[System.Text.Encoding]` instances directly - you're no longer limited to a handful of predefined ones.

Comment: Nice!  I've had to specify the encoding as a variable assigned a value from `[System.Text.Encoding]` in the past to specify UTF8-BOM for .xml files and such, but this is good to know if our company ever allows us to upgrade to PowerShell (Core) 7.